# after installing ruby 2.3.1 with ruby-install, it is still showing the older version of ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3, ruby-install

I used ruby-install to install ruby 2.3.1 , when I do a "ruby -v" it is still showing the older 1.9 version.

The instructions here https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install is what I used to install ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Did you restart your shell to pick up the updated path?

Comment: I looked for a .profile file and could not find one, "echo $PATH" shows me what is in the path but I can't figure out where its getting the path info from.

I guess I don't know where ruby-install puts ruby when it installs it.

Comment: That's all interesting, but you didn't answer the question - did you restart the shell?  Shut down the old shell, fire up a new one?

Comment: I did do that and it did fix it, thanks for the help.